# Symfony 3.4 pdfmerger

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, merge

By searching the web, Github, Stack overflow and etc. for a solution of my task i a haven't found a **clear**, **simple** and free way to do it. If anyone could share the knowledge I would really appreciate it. By reading similar Stack Overflow questions, got somehow even more confused...

Task:
 - Simple web app for PDF merging. User uploads PDF's of **any version, compression or complexity** and merges them into one PDF.

Front End:

- Bootstrap
- Font Awesome
- Bootstrap fileinput plugin + jQuery

Back End:

- PHP 7.1
- Symfony 3.4.4
- MySQL
- PDF merging library

PROBLEM:

I have tried many PDF file merging implementations (around 5 to be exact)  accessible over the GitHub. The list is this:

1. https://github.com/rguedes/PDFMerger - Decent solution, but unfortunately does not supports some PDF versions (compression error thrown).
2. https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger - A more promising solution implementing TCPDF, but unfortunately have some compatibility problems with class loading. Even if class loading errors are fixed manually, still throws odd errors on some PDF's (cant read file and doesn't return number of pages).
3. https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI - Tried this library, but it's apparently have a payed addon to be able to read new PDF versions (>=1.5).
4. Some other libraries similar to the 1. and 2.

So now I **can** merge simple PDF files even of version 1.7 (why ?). **But** if they have some complex content like annotations or etc. an error is thrown that PDF file has unsupported compression.

And I actually wanted to ask if anyone can help me to find a solution **before** I will need to dig into https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF and invest DAYS into figuring this out. If possible I would want to avoid such waste of time for such a simple project...

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried ghostscript?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Interesting idea, I will try it and write back as soon as possible. 
P.S. Do you have any recommendations on what **gs** PHP libraries (drivers) can be effectively used with Symfony 3.4.* ?